# How to add Javamail API source code in eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-mail

what are the steps to add source code of Javamail API in my project so that i can see javamail classes easily by clicking on its class from my project. I am using eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack overflow.

There are basically two methods of doing this.

### Method 1: The 'Easy' way.

You use Maven, If your project is a maven project. include the dependency for javamail. Right click on your project and select **Maven > Download Sources**
[image]
this should basically download the Source files for all your dependencies.

### Method 2: The 'Hard' Way

Go to this [link](https://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads) and download your Javamail 1.5 jar. and This [link](https://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/directory/source) to download your Javamail 1.5 source jar. Next step, Right click on your Project, select **Properties**. Select **Java Build Path**, Click the **Libraries Tab** and Click **Add external Jars**.
[image]

Browse to the location of your library and Add it. Expand the javamail library.
Click **Source attachment** and click the **Edit** button.
[image]
Browse to the location of your source zip file and add it.

You should now be able to see your Source javadocs, Control Clicking on a Javamail Class, should take you to the source Class as well.

Answer (score 0):

easy way to attach source to any jar file       http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-attach-source-in-eclipse-Jar-JDK-debugging.html